# How to replace \r\n to \n in Windows in a large text file?

Tags: windows, newlines

I have a text file in my Windows computer of size about 8 MB. I wanted to replace all the \r\n line-breaks to \n line-break (around 2*10^5 replacements) in the file. However, the only way I know is using Notepad++ to do it, which hangs while replacing all in this file. What other methods are available?

Comment: Write a script to do it.  Just read a line and write it back without the \r.  You can use vbscript or javascript.  Alternatively powershell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325953/how-can-i-replace-newlines-using-powershell

Comment: Are you using a macro to do this in Notepad++? When it hangs, it's only the screen refresh which hangs, it still updates the text in the background. You could batch it and do `xxxx` lines at a time.

Comment: @cup I am not much familiar with Powershell. Can you tell me if this command will work according to what I understood from the link?
> Get-Content test.txt |% {$_-replace "`r`n", "`n"}

Comment: @spikey_richie I was using Find and Replace. For some time, nothing happens on the screen and then the window changes to 'not responding'. I have to do this for a lot of files so batching might be inefficient.

Comment: Doesn't Notepad++ have a proper option under the Edit menu to do this? Probably faster than find/replace... `Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be patient and use the built-in tool.

`Edit` -> `EOL Conversion` -> `Unix (LF)`

In a 6MB file with 1,048,577 lines it takes approximately 30 seconds for my computer. Your "2*10^5" is presumably 200,000 lines so should be somewhat quicker.

It saying "not responding" does not mean that the program has crashed. Just give it time.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this in Notepad++ (Edit → EOL conversion) on a 7MB, 200,000 line file, this took ~3 seconds.

A slightly faster way, if you have some kind of Linux available (I used Windows Subsystem for Linux), is the command `dos2unix filename.txt`. This took ~1 second on my machine.